# Get Wordpress to Coincide with Zend Framework at the base level

Tags: php, zend-framework, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have a current wordpress blog with the blog posts URLs structured as http://somedomain.com/2010/02/postname

I'm now installing a zend framework implementation at the base level http://somedomain.com/

I DON'T  want my blog to have a different url structure. like http://somedomain.com/blog/2010/02/article-name

Any ideas on how I can best keep the old url structure and still have zend framework live at /

My thought was move the blog to /blog and do a url rewrite in there to make everything appear as though its at / , but i don't think that will work ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subdomain for your site. wordpress.site.com is for wordpress, zend.site.com is for your zend code. Of course you should use better names than that but you get the idea.

if you are using apache, put this in your .conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/www/html/blog
    ServerName blog.site.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/www/html/zend
    ServerName zend.site.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Well i can' t do this, because i may was well change the directory structure. 
The whole idea is to keep the 'google linkjuice' of the incoming links at 
http://somedomain/2010/02/postname

changing that to http://blog.somedomain.com would break the links.  Thank you though

Comment: Then only add a subdomain for the zend code, and leave wordpress as is.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite could do this, provided that your Zend controllers only have [a..z] chars.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: What happens if you have a wordpress page and zend page that have the same name? This is a recipe for confusion and frustration.

Comment: I think i'll have to use this approach. zend at the top level and i'll redirect everything except /2009 and /2010 to index.php for zend dispatch. and redirect /2009 and /2010 for wordpress to handle